# VBA find cell address with nth value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find cell address with nth occurrence of the value.

Example: I want to know cell address of the 3rd X in the column.

```
| Andy | X |
| Tony | Y |
| Luke | X |
| Anne | X |
```

and the result should be B4.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So what attempt have you made? What code do you have?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub FindAddress()

Dim stringToFind As String: stringToFind = "X"
Dim timesOfOccurence As Long: timesOfOccurence = 3 'we want third occurence
Dim columnToSearch As Long: columnToSearch = 2 'we search second column - B column
Dim counter As Long: counter = 0
Dim i As Long, occurences As Long


For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, columnToSearch).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, columnToSearch) = stringToFind Then
        occurences = occurences + 1
    End If
    If occurences = timesOfOccurence Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If occurences = timesOfOccurence Then
    MsgBox ("Column: " & columnToSearch & " || Row: " & i)
Else
    MsgBox ("Specified string didn't occur that many times")
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this, using the Find and FindNext methods:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
icounter = 0
Set valuefound = ws.Columns("B:B").Find(What:="X")
'above look for value X in column B
If Not valuefound Is Nothing Then 'if found then
    foundaddress = valuefound.Address 'save the address of the first instance found
    icounter = icounter + 1 'increment counter
    Do
        Set valuefound = ws.Columns("B:B").FindNext(valuefound) 'find next value
        icounter = icounter + 1 'increment counter
        If icounter = 3 Then MsgBox valuefound.Offset(0, -1).Value 'if third instance found then prompt name of person
    Loop While Not valuefound Is Nothing And valuefound.Address <> foundaddress
End If
End Sub
```